# We have two different ISPs on two different routers, why do both have intermittent connectivity issues?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, gateway, intranet

We have tried everything to get internet working from one end of the property to the other and each end has a separate ip from different providers. and for some reason both the cable company and centurylink networks drop connections periodically, become slow or completely cut out momentarily.
We have a few dozen smart devices like light bulbs and electrical switches and security cameras, several alexas, and various laptops and smart TVs.  We tried using velop mesh nodes and that made things worse.
We recently bought a few pi’s to try and build some kind of gateway intranet to put all the smart devices on hoping to clear up the network congestion, but so far I’ve only got one up and running home assistant, it’s not separated from the rest of the traffic and now the internet is even slower.
Why would both networks be spotty?  We had a technician come out from Cox when we couldn’t get any of the five different brand new routers to work with thier modem and he couldn’t figure out what the problem was so we had to use their router in order to even have internet access at all.

Is this a connection issue somewhere outside of our control or do we just really not know what we’re doing? How can I make things work smoothly?

Comment: Are wired connections affected too, or just Wi-Fi?

Comment: It will drop wired connections as well, the speed seems the same or close whether wired or not